# EF- Replacing inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

I am using inheritance currently in EF and feel like it is causing more issues than it is helping, especially with binding an aggregation of tables to a datagrid. I have given a screen of part of the model. What I am trying to do is bind `FREQUENCY` to a datagrid, and have the grid fields be based on the type of `FREQ_POOL`(which is a base class). So for instance, if I want a `POOL_IA` datagrid, then it would have those fields, as well as the few fields in `FREQUENCY`. I was using inheritance because it made since from an OO perspective. The alternative is to just have lots of 0..1 relationships that show the ability for `FREQ_POOL` to have an extension, but then I have no constraint in place saying that `FREQ_POOL` can only be ONE type. What is a better design to accomplish this and make data binding easier? Thank you for any guidance.

[image]

Comment: Been down that road, and I personally ended up with lots of 0/1 relationships instead of inheritance.  I never bothered trying to enforce the "of only one type" at a database constraint level, other than having a column on the parent table that indicated what it represented just so code had a way of knowing which child entity to retrieve.  Certainly performed much better than inheritance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes a lot of sense. I wish it was easier to work with inheritance in EF.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be creating a data grid that gets the data from `FREQ_POOL` and then put all the variables of `POOL_IA` (or the all the properties of derived class using reflection) and `FREQUENCY` .

If you really don't need using objects while binding your data grid and able to use DataSet the another approach may be getting all the properties and the values of entry with Context.Entry method   on the fly and put it into DataSet dynamically.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I am worried that the new row creation process will be complex, as in order for a new row to be created I essentially have to do everything manually(which is fine if that is how it has to be).